# Use a collection view in a popover iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover, collectionview

I want to have a collection view in a popover. So first I set up my Collection view controller and my custom cell. When I start the program from here it works fine.

In another view controller I created a popover controller with the collection view as its content. When I hit a toolbar button, the popover needs to become active.

When I run the simulator I get this error:

> 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier CameraSystemCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Here is my **viewcontroller.m** code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CameraSystemMenuViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    CameraSystemMenuViewController *cameraSystemMenu;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize cameraSystemButton = _cameraSystemButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    cameraSystemMenu = [[CameraSystemMenuViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:cameraSystemMenu];
    [popoverController setDelegate:self];

}

- (IBAction)cameraSystemSelectButton:(id)sender
{
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];

}
@end
```

And here is my cellForItemAtIndexPath in **CameraSystemMenuViewController.m**:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CameraSystemCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CameraSystemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell collectionImageView] setImage:cameraImage];
    cell.cameraSystemName.text = [cameraNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    return cell;
}
```

The Cell Identifier is correct & the storyboard cell has the right custom class. 
I don't have to register because I am using a custom cell that is in the storyboard.
What to do?

Comment: Just one doubt `CameraSystemMenuViewController` is collectionViewController? set up in storyboard???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I can understand is you are trying to set up `UICollectionViewController` in storyboard. It will give you a collection view with prototype cell (`I don't have to register because I am using a custom cell that is in the storyboard`). If I understood wrongly just ignore it. 
  But in `viewController` you are instantiating collectionViewController again not using from storyboard.  **So  instead of**

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
cameraSystemMenu = [[CameraSystemMenuViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
```

**Use**

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    cameraSystemMenu =   [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraSystemMenuViewController"];
```

Give a try..:)